# Executor map does not appear to be processing generator

Tags: python, parallel-processing, process, generator, concurrent.futures

This is my first time working with `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor()`.

I am attempting to concurrently process data from an iterable across all my CPUs with `Executor.map()`. However, the function supplied to that method does not seem to be executing.

The iterable I am working with is a generator. I tried converting the generator to a list before passing it to `Executor.map()` with `list()`, which takes a long time, but still the handler function was not invoked.

I've tried increasing the `chunksize` attribute of `Executor.map()` to 100, but this did not seem to have any effect.

```py
def delete_tickets(tickets):
    print('==> Deleting chunk of tickets')  # never appears in my terminal
    zenpy_client.tickets.delete(tickets)
    return 'success'

# this is a generator with a length of 1,512
tickets = zenpy_client.search(type='ticket', tags=DELETE_WITH_TAG)

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    # also tried
    # tickets = list(tickets)
    # same result (nothing happens)
    for result in executor.map(delete_tickets, tickets, chunksize=100):
        print(result)
```

In the example above, `delete_tickets()` does not appear to ever be executed. The `print()` statement within that function does not appear in my terminal, and the chunk of tickets is not deleted.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I suspect that the executor is simply materializing your generator before chunking the args.

Comment: Alternatively, maybe your `zenpy_client` isn't playing nicely with multiprocessing, which involves pickling and sending it to all the processes.

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga. I updated my description above to show that I've also tried converting the generator to a list before mapping, but I end up with the same problem.

Comment: Does it ever get to the line after `tickets = list(tickets)`? Because if that is a problem there, then essentially the same thing happens in `executor.map`, and the chunksize or any of that won't help.

Comment: Yes, it does. Converting to a list  takes several minutes, but it does successfully complete.

Comment: Then I suspect the generator aspect is a red-herring. Probably, there is some issue with multiprocessing and the client library objects that are being used.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using a ProcessPoolExecutor instead of a ThreadPoolExecutor? The latter is considered a better approach for IO-bound operations such as calling an API via a client, which I guess is what you are doing.